# Get number of video views from a video tweet

Tags: twitter, twitter-rest-api

I'm looking for a way to get the number of video views from a video tweet.

With the search/tweets I can get the number of favorites and retweets but not the views. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the twitter ads api [there is a video metric](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/analytics/overview/metrics-and-segmentation) where is possible to get the number of views. The problem is that it requires to be approved through the twitter review process and this api looks more like a way to fully manage the ads of the user.

But I finally found an undocumented api where I can get this information using the same access token used for everything else:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/videos/tweet/config/{{id-tweet}}.json
```

Among other things, it returns a track.viewCount field.

Comment: Thanks for the info, do you mind if I ask how you include the API key / authentication in the URL you provided?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. The Twitter Ads API claims to be able to pull video views but there is no mention of what the node would be called: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/analytics/overview.html